# Changing Property in ThicknessAnimation

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation

I'm using a label in my project to show some news in moving style by thicknessanimation, but I can't change the content of label after the animation completes. What can I do?

First when the window loads I activate a thicknessanimation with the code below

```
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard TargetName="MyLabel">
                <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" SpeedRatio="0.8" RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                    FillBehavior="HoldEnd" From="0,0,0,0" To="100,0,0,0" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

Then I Set a Style on the label

```
<Style TargetType="Label">
<Style.Triggers>    
  <MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
      <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyLabel, Path=Margin}" Value="100,0,0,0" />
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapes" />
  </MultiDataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

I tried to change the content with IsVisibleChanged but it didn't work.

Comment: how you tried changing the label content?

Comment: please provide more of your code. I don´t see any animation related code. Besides that, is a value of "Collapes" actually working for the visibility property? Shouldn´t it be "Collapsed"?

Comment: Please Explain Briefly

Comment: i found my answer you can see link below [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30458484/marquee-text-witl-multi-content/30644178#30644178)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code snippet the first issue is your MultiDataTrigger. You have the condition and the setter backwards try something like this and see if it works

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
<MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
  <Condition Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
</MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
<Setter Binding="{Binding ElementName=Label1, Path=Margin}" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
```

The **Condition** tag is for the event or property you're looking for to trigger the **Setter** tag which will set the properties of the element you want to change.

Also a MultiDataTrigger is probably not the tag you need to change the margin this code should be a bit simpler

```
<Style TargetType="Label">
<Style.Triggers>    
<Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed">
<Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="MyLabel" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
</Trigger> 
</Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: Just to make sure I have this right, what you want is to change the margin of the label if the label is collapsed correct? If so then what exactly doesn't work? The code I posted requires you to set the margin property to your specifications so instead of 0, 0, 0, 0 you need to change that to whatever you want. Or is there another issue that you're having?

Comment: i found my answer you can see link below [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30458484/marquee-text-witl-multi-content/30644178#30644178)