# Marquee Text witl multi content

Tags: wpf, animation, text, marquee

I am trying to use a text marquee like on this post
[Marquee Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002271/smooth-text-animation-marquee-using-wpf)

But i dont know how can i change the textblock content after a cycle of animation.
thanks for your help.

---

I really stuck. please help me.

Comment: Please add the relevant technology tags  (eg. javascript, WPF, Java, etc...) so this question can be picked up by people with relevant knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found my answer

```
<TextBlock x:Name="_box" FontSize="64"  Text="My Simple Text.">
    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform x:Name="AnimatedTranslateTransform" X="0" Y="0" />
    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
    <TextBlock.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBlock.Loaded">
          <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard  Name="MyStorybord">
              <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetName="AnimatedTranslateTransform" 
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                From="-300" To="300" Duration="0:0:5" 
                Completed="Timeline_OnCompleted" />
            </Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
      </TextBlock.Triggers>
</TextBlock>
```

this cause the text box move one time. in method "Timeline_OnCompleted" I Change the Text And start the animation again.

```
        private void Timeline_OnCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _box.Text = MytextArray[index];
        BeginStoryboard(MyStorybord);
    }
```

thanks.